# How do I Retrive values from my form to be used later?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have created a form using Javascript and html and it looks like this:

```
function testResults (form) {
    var TestVar = form.inputbox.value;
    var formData = $('#vibhu').serialize();
    formData = JSON.stringify(formData);
    if (window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem('formData', formData);

<h1 class="title">Create Event</h1>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET"><BR>
Event Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" VALUE=""><P>
Date and Time: <INPUT TYPE="datetime-local" NAME="date" Value=""><P>
Event Location: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="location" VALUE=""><P>
Event Notes<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="notes" VALUE=""><P>
```

I have attempted to retrive this on another webpage using

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
localStorage.getItem("myForm");
}
</script>
```

How do I go about being able to retrive this information and display it back to the user on another page as an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using localStorage?
To store an item, use `localStorage.setItem("valuename", "data");`.
And to get an item's value, use `localStorage.getItem("valuename");`.
Here is an example:

```
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET"><BR>
Event Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" VALUE="" id="input1"><P>
Event Date and Time: <INPUT TYPE="datetime-local" NAME="date" Value="" id="input2"><P>
Event Location: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="location" VALUE="" id="input3"><P>
Event Notes: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="notes" VALUE="" id="input4"><P>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
   document.getElementById('input1').value = localStorage.getItem("EventName");
   document.getElementById('input2').value = localStorage.getItem("EventDateAndTime");
   document.getElementById('input3').value = localStorage.getItem("EventLocation");
   document.getElementById('input4').value = localStorage.getItem("EventNotes");
</script>

<script>
   function myFunction() {
      localStorage.setItem("EventName", document.getElementById('input1').value);
      localStorage.setItem("EventDateAndTime", document.getElementById('input2').value);
      localStorage.setItem("EventLocation", document.getElementById('input3').value);
      localStorage.setItem("EventNotes", document.getElementById('input4').value);
   }
</script>
```

And here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/eYpdmQb

Comment: Thats very useful, thanks @marshmallow, how would i go about displaying this local storage data on a different page?

Comment: @LachlanD Are you the owner of this page? Can you modify its code?

Answer (score 0):

use the `submit` with `action` attribute of `form`
like this

```
<form name="myform" action="./html2.html" method="GET">
Event Name: <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
Event Date and Time: <input type="datetime-local" name="date" value=""/>
Event Location: <input type="text" name="location" value=""/>
Event Notes: <input type="text" name="notes" value=""/>
<input value="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

when you click the submit button, the page while jump to `html2.html?name=xxx&date=xxx&location=xxx...`